# Inhibit focus stealing when launching a new graphics plot in r

Tags: r

I am familar with matlab, but relatively new to r. I have an r script which produces many different graphical plot windows and takes some time in between each one. While this is running, I tend to be working on other things. The problem is every time a new graphics window is produced, it steals the focus, redirecting keyboard input away from what i am doing. Is there a way in r to prevent focus stealing when a graphical plot is produced?

I have searched everywhere but failed to find any reference to this. I am working in linux.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: How are you creating each plot window? The same window is re-used by default...

Comment: The more I think about this, why do you need this? Do you intend to create a bunch of open plot windows? Or do you just want to save those plots using something like `pdf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `wmctrl` is installed on your system, you can avoid losing focus by redefining the `plot` function like this:

```
plot <- function(...) {
  graphics::plot(...)
  system("wmctrl -a :ACTIVE:")
}
```

It seems to work quite well, in the fluxbox window manager at least. I tried different scenarios like switching to a different window during a long calculation before `plot` is called, and opening multiple plots.

Put it into your `.Rprofile` if you want it to persist.

Comment: This looks promising - i haven't got wmctrl on my system (opensuse with gnome) but will install it and test and post back here if it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Only on Windows: try putting a `bringToTop(-1)` in your function:

```
z <- function() {
  plot(1:3)
  bringToTop(-1)
}
z()
```

It will temporarily steal focus but then return it.

Another strategy on Windows:

```
z <-  function(){
    windows(restoreConsole=TRUE)
    plot(1)
}
z()
```

I'm still thinking here...

Comment: `bringToTop` is a Windows-specific function. It doesn't exist in R installs on linux.

Comment: `windows` is also (surprise, surprise) Windows-specific. ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you are more interested in doing something else while the plots are being produced then I would suggest opening a pdf device so that all the plots go to a pdf file in the background and do not interfere with whatever else you are doing.  Then when you are ready to look through the plots you just open the pdf file and look at the plots (and you can easily go back to previous plots this way).

Comment: Thanks - that's a good idea but isn't quite what i'm looking for as the plots are also emailed out separately, one per email.

Comment: @user1218475, then send each plot to its own file.  See the `onefile` argument to `pdf` or other file based plotting devices, or use `dev.off` after each plot and control the filenames yourself.  If the main purpose is to e-mail the plots then sending them directly to files will be more efficient than popping up many windows and having to work with each window afterwards.